# Boxer semantic parser download

Tags: parsing, semantics

I was curious if anyone knew of a separate repository (or if you have your own version or a C&C tool login that I could use) of the Boxer semantic parser? I'm trying to download this from the developer's website (http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/Installation) but everytime I register, it says that 1) there's an error with my registration but I don't know what else to fill or 2) it leads to me a page where it says script failed..

Anyways, let me know what you all think. I wasn't sure which forum to post this on (this could also fall under the software recommendations, open source stackexchange sites, and many others) so I apologize if this is in the wrong site. Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to download this from an alternate source? The link also doesn't work for me

Comment: There was another comment on this post to personally send an email to one of the developers working with Boxer but I suppose that someone deleted the comment. I don't have that email anymore but someone did setup a web API for use Boxer. Here's the link: http://valeriobasile.github.io/candcapi/

Comment: What did you exactly want to use it for? Did you want to develop it further or just to use it?

Comment: I was searching for some code related to "LODifier", and then i stumbled upon https://github.com/vimalkumarpatel/cs586 which uses candc and boxer, so I wanted to test it out. Cannot find other reproducible codes for the paper :\

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - When it was up - the site where the Boxer semantic parser was housed had glitches where I couldn't register and/or download the software. I sent a ticket to them a while back but no response.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! :) will look elsewhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I too, was not able to download the source files from the link. I got in touch with [Dr. Valerio Basile](http://valeriobasile.github.io/). He pointed me to his github repository (https://github.com/valeriobasile/learningbyreading). Check out the ext/candc folder under it. You can get the source files of C&C and Boxer form there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: This does provide an answer to the question as this repo does contain the Boxer parser.